# Produce a number such that the digits of the number should be maximum of the digits of the numbers in a given array

Tags: java

I have a method that should produce a number such that the digits of the number should be maximum of the digits of the numbers in a given array. For example if the given array is {32,145,1064}, the units maximum is 5, tens maximum is 6, hundreds maximum is 1,etc. So the number produced should be 1165. Similarly {638,245,2482} should produce 2688.
I have done the following but that updates only the unit digit.

```
public void produceNumber(int[] arr)
{
    int num = arr[0];
    for(int i=1;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        int temp = num;
        while(arr[i] > 0)
        {
            if(arr[i] % 10 > temp % 10)
                num = (num/10)*10 + arr[i]%10;//Line 10
            arr[i] /= 10;
            temp /= 10;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(num);
}
```

Something is going wrong in line 10. Please suggest a way to do this.

Comment: the problem is not really line 10 but your general logic of the "algorithm", at least I dont see how this implementation will get you even close to the output. I would iterate over the "digits" in the first for loop, first the units, then the tens, etc. *Inside* the loop iterate over the array, look at the specific digit value of each array entry and find the max there.

Comment: I would recommend converting all the int numbers into strings, so that you can have an inverted loop as @luk2302 mentions going over the units, then the tens and so on.

Comment: I feel, converting number to string will spoil the challenge

Comment: Another thing you can do to determine the resulting number digits can be to first get the maximum number from the array, and from that you can determine how many digits your answer can have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea is close but not quite right. You can do something like the following to achieve the wanted outcome:

```
int produceNumber(int [] arr)
{

    int [] amx = new int[10];
    int mx = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        int idx = 0;
        while(arr[i] > 0)
        {
            amx[idx] = Math.max(amx[idx], arr[i] % 10);
            arr[i] /= 10;
            idx++;
            mx = Math.max(mx, idx);
        }
    }

    //now build the number
    int res = 0, factor = 1;
    for(int i=0; i<mx;i++){
        res += amx[i] * factor;
        factor *= 10;
    }

    return res;
}
```

In the sample I limited the size of the array to 10, so I assume that the maximum number is at most 10 digits long, but you can change it if you like.

PS: You may need to do small corrections somewhere since I wrote it directly in C++ and only afterwards I noticed it was tagged java.